# Layout XML View IDs and R problems

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-resources, r.java-file

I am creating a layout in XML, and I have noticed this very strange occurrence. It has never happened before, but lately it's been getting on my nerves. I kind of want to abandon Eclipse and find a better IDE because of it.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/action_search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="kkm" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/actions_list"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/cancel_action_selection"
        android:layout_below="@id/action_search_bar" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_preview_pane"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/actions_list"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/actions_list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actions_list"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="kk" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_action_selection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/define_new_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cancel_action_selection"
        android:text="NEW" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/define_new_action"
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: What I am trying to achieve]

The problem is, if I try to set the ListView to be above the cancel button (via android:layout_above), it will say that it can't find the id for the cancel button.

Now, what I have noticed is that if I try and specify any ids for layouts BEFORE they are created with @+id, then I will get that strange error. What I mean by this is the following:

In the XML, apparently IDs have to be declared in order. Strange, no?
I would have to declare the cancel button's id first with @+id way before I define the ListView and set its layout_above attribute.

If I try to do what I have done here, it will say that it cannot find the id for the cancel button.

I have tried cleaning the project, ending adb.exe, refreshing, etc. and all it does is corrupt my project even more. R is not even generated afterwards. I don't want to have to go in a loop problem after problem because Eclipse can't handle things like this properly.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Or a better IDE?

Comment: you need to have cancel button id first coz you are placing listview relative to the cancel button.

Comment: @Raghunandan Is that how it works with RelativeLayouts? Do I have to do the same thing for LinearLayouts?

Comment: LinearLayouts are different. For relative layouts you are placing your views relative to the other view. so you will need the id of the button first and then relative to the button place the listview

Comment: Ohhhhhhh. I see. Thank you then. Why don't you go ahead and post your reply as an answer? I'll select it. (Also, sorry for my apparent frustration in my question. It's been driving me crazy all day.)

Comment: check the links in the answer posted. it will clear your doubts. also check the example posted there

Comment: @TonyN.Tran You _don't_ need to define the `cancel` button before the `listview`. Xml is parsed from top to bottom. So, all eclipse/android needs from you is an `id`. `Ids` are declared using `@+id` and referenced using `@id`. Since `cancel` button is defined later than `listview`, you need `android:layout_above="@+id/cancel_action_selection"`(mind the `+` there). Now, when the layout is inflated, `listview` will be placed as required, even though `cancel` button is encountered later.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

**RelativeLayout lets child views specify their position relative to the parent view or to each other (specified by ID)**. So you can align two elements by right border, or make one below another, centered in the screen, centered left, and so on.

So you are placing listview relative to the button cancel. So you need to define button with a id. Position the listview relative to the button.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

There is an example in the links posted both for linearlayout and relative layout have a look at it.

Edit:

If you have errors in your resource files R.java will not be generated. So make sure you do not have errors in your resource files and then clean and build the project.

To clarify the confusion. Note `android:layout_above="@+id/button1"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OtherScreenActivity1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
             >
        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Same as above

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OtherScreenActivity1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        </ListView>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You have this

```
  android:layout_above="@id/cancel_action_selection"
```

Use

```
  android:layout_above="@+id/cancel_action_selection"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html.

Look at the attribute id in the above link

Comment: `So you need to define button with a id first. Position the listview relative to the button`: Just so you know, this is not required.

Comment: @user2558882 why is that. if you are using relative layout how would you position listview relative to the button or you are suggesting place button relative to listview?. I am not talking about the position of button in the xml. you can have button first then listview. i am talking about button having id first

Comment: Thank you for making the necessary correction. I guess you meant something else when you wrote `you need to define button with a id first`.

Comment: @user2558882 thanks for commenting and letting me know i guess the word first mislead others. I changed it.